# Joining columns categorical and numerical from two dataframes using groupby Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

> The following is the required format i need to generate a report from CSV file

````
User_Name Disposition_Code   Call_Received Calls Abandoned
0   person1           Solved      2            4
1   person2           Solved      1            4
2   person1           Solved      2            3
3   person2       Not_Solved      1            1
4   person3           Solved      11           0


total_record = test.groupby("User Name").agg({"Calls_Received": ['sum']
                                                 , "Calls Abandoned": ['sum']
                                                 , "Total Served In Target %": ['mean']
                                                 , "Total Served After Target": ['sum']})```
````

**The result is**

```
User_Name Calls_Received Calls Abandoned
person 1      4                 7
person 2      2                 5
person 3      11                0
```

> Now i want to add

```
User_Name Calls_Received Calls Abandoned Solved Not_Solved
person 1      4                 7           2       0
person 2      2                 5           1       1
person 3      11                0           1       0
```

> Please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
total_record = total_record.join(pd.crosstab(test['User_Name'], test['isposition_Code']))
```